# EntityFramework 6 DatabaseFirst add navigation property from code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have (can`t change) EF DataBase first project without navigation property in models.

I want extend autogenerated models and add navigation property

1. Generated model

```cs
//generated.cs

public partial class company
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public partial class user
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int company_id { get; set; }
}
```

2. I want add navigation property from code

```cs
//model_extension.cs

public partial class user
{
    public company Company { get; set; }
}
```

I have exception "The specified type member 'Company' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

I work with CodeFirst before.

I understand, I must link  user.company_id to Company
But not understand how make this with code (not designer)

Comment: Sounds like you need `ICollection`: `public ICollection<company> Company { get; set; }`. You can't directly define a model class as navigation property without wrapping it to a supported collection first.

Comment: I need Company. Get all users with company - db.users.Include(x => x.Company).ToList(). But I don`t want change .edmx

Comment: You should have foreign key in your tables. DbFirst will automatically create navigation property while generating the Model.

Comment: Seems that error generated from your LINQ query. If you're don't want to change EDMX later to regenerate model code, put `public ICollection<company> Company { get; set; }` directly on `user` class declaration & use foreign key relationship for both tables.

Comment: And use virtual keyword while associating it.

Comment: I guess you are using Entity Framework designer. There you should have the option for specifying company_id as foreign key, which will automatically generate the navigation property

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto User have only one company not ICollection

Comment: use like this: public virtual company Company { get; set; }

Comment: @AbhayDixit I not use virtual I use .Include where I need load navigation property

Comment: public partial class user
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int company_id { get; set; } 
public virtual company Company { get; set; } 
}

Answer (score 1):

In Database First Approach, You are generating your POCO objects from database schema via `Entity Framework Designer/ADO.NET Entity Data Model` so it is not flexible as Code-First, you need to go on database, and change the schema yourself and update your `.edmx` file. while adding properties to these Models are possible in c# side, but they are not going to be added to your database schema,

I suggest your reverse your database schema and go as Code-First Approach, This [nuget package](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator) can do this for you.

After Reversing It's all about Code-First then, creating your own `DbContext` and `OnModelCreating` and let the Migration handle the rest. Then you can use Eager Loading of EF to load your data,